# Reading and Parsing HTML Files

Tags: html, parsing

I need to read some html files and manipulate them through parsing. Those files are in a dir and I need to change some menu linkings and need to remove the top-menu and stuff like that.

Can you guys help me with it - I prefer taking java cause its the language im used to the most. But if there are more easier ways, then let me know guys.

Thanks for your help already!

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use nodejs and library like https://cheerio.js.org

That's pretty easy to get all files in directory and parse or do whatever you want:

Here is base steps:

1. Init new project (you need node js installed on your system):

```
mkdir project
cd project
npm init -y
npm install cheerio --save
touch index.js
```

2. write a little bit code:

```js
// index.js 
const fs = require('fs')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
fs.readDirSync('/path/to/your/directory/with/html/files')
.filter(name => /\.html$/.test(name)) // ensure you get html files only
.map( name => ({name, content: fs.readFileSync(name)})) // convert to object containing file name and its content
.forEach(({name, content}) => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(content)
  // Here is magic, that allows you to manipulate your HTML in jQuery way 
  // ... your manipulations
  // ... 

  // Saving new processed file
  fs.writeFileSync(`processed_${name}`, $.html())
})
```

3. Run your code

```
node index.js
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Evgeny for you fast help, ill try it out asap!!!